# Multiple Controllers in AngularApp not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've got two controllers within the same app, yet it seems only one is being registered:

```
var app = angular.module('MyModule', []);

app.controller('FruitCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
});

app.controller('VegetableCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.vegetables = ['potato', 'beans', 'onions'];
});
```

My template:

```
<div ng-app="MyModule">

    <div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">{{fruit}}</div>
    </div>

    <div controller="VegetableCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="vegetable in vegetables">{{vegetable}}</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Only the "fruits" section is being rendered.

See also the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/doque/9wfhsgqf/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the ng- of ng-controller on the vegetables repeat

http://jsfiddle.net/9wfhsgqf/3/

```
<div ng-app="MyModule">

<div ng-controller="VegetableCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="vegetable in vegetables">{{vegetable}}</div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">{{fruit}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
controller="VegetableCtrl"
```

should be

```
ng-controller="VegetableCtrl"
```

Answer (score 1):

change from

```
<div controller="VegetableCtrl">
```

to

```
<div ng-controller="VegetableCtrl">
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
<div controller="VegetableCtrl">
```

with

```
<div ng-controller="VegetableCtrl">
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the 'ng-' from the second div, it should be 'ng-controller' not just controller